# parallax horizontal navigation with javascript

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, parallax

I'm studying parallax and horizontal scrolling website and I get in touch with this fantastic website: http://www.black5.de/

Exploring with firebug I found that their developers:

- use absolute positioned elements
- use a non-scrolling container
- recreate a custom navigation controller using arrow keys, mouse wheel and in-page anchor

I tried to re-implement this logic here: http://www.albertobottarini.com/parallax/index-manual.html

As you can see anchor links works but navigation with arrows and mouse wheel don't works (and it's correct because I don't create custom controllers for them). Implementing custom navigation seems very hard job (for example I have to take care about user keep pressing arrow key because they want to speed up navigation).
I tried some other jquery plugin (like jparallax) but the resulted webpage is the same as mine where everything seems choppy and jerky.

How can I recreate the fluidity and pleasantness of www.black5.de? Do you think it will be a huge project? Do you know some useful library/plugin?

Thanks

Comment: "fluidity and pleasantness of www.black5.de" Well, this site has really slow load times in Europe and the animations are bumpy. Juts use a ready to go parallax plugin instead of re-implementing something new. One I used currently is [jparallax](https://github.com/stephband/jparallax) and it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm from Italy ;) I didn't refer to loading time but fluidity of navigation using mouse wheel or arrow keys. Elements seems to be floated on background and it's cool. It's not like my example where everything is "docked" and navigation is jerky.